# slicing and range of a python exercise

Tags: python

I am a beginner with Python and would very much appreciate some help with a doubt I have.
So I found this exercise in a website: Return the total count of sub-string “Emma” appears in the given string. Given string is “Emma is good developer. Emma is a writer”. But I don't fully understand the solution.
solution:

```
def count_emma(statement):
    print("Given String: ", statement)
    count = 0
    for i in range(len(statement) - 1):
        count += statement[i: i + 4] == 'Emma'
    return count

count = count_emma("Emma is good developer. Emma is a writer")
print("Emma appeared ", count, "times")
```

what does it mean exactly the -1 in:

```
range(len(statement)-1):
```

And what does it mean the [i: i + 4] in:

```
count += statement[i: i + 4] == 'Emma'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`range(len(statement)-1)` means to loop over each number from 0 to the length of statement - 1. This solution doesn't have to consider the last element because there are zero characters in statement after the last element*.

`count += statement[i: i+4] == 'Emma'` increments count by 1 if the 4 characters of the statement sliced starting from i and ending at i+4 (not inclusive). This works because booleans are actually just a special case of integers, where True is represented by 1 and False is represented by 0. As a result, if 'Emma' isn't equal to statement[i: i+4], 0 is added (no effect), and if it is, then 1 is added.

*The solution could stop after `len(statement) - 4` because the last 3 characters also can't match the 4-character target string 'Emma'.

Answer (score 0):

The `statement[i: i + 4]` is a slice, taking the characters from `i` (inclusive) to `i+4` (exclusive) and comparing those to the string `"Emma"`. As long as the first value (the start) is within the bounds of the string, it does not matter if the second value (the end) is out-of-bounds; it will just mean that it returns a shorter substring.

Consequently, the `-1` in `range(len(statement)-1)` does not serve any purpose here. What it does it it makes the loop stop one earlier, when `i` is the second-to-last character, but it would work just as well without the -1.

Having said that, you could also just use `statement.count("Emma"))` to get the count of the substring `"Emma"` (note that this will not count overlapping matches, though)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, A string slice returns a sub-string of that string EG. `"string"[1:4]` becomes `tri`.

Now, `statement[i:i+4]` is checking the next 4 letters from the current point in the loop. So if `i` is 2 then `statement[i:i+4]` is `ma a`. When `i` is 24 `statement[i:i+4]` is `Emma` . So when i=0 or i=24, `statement[i:i+4] == "Emma"` will be True.

True and False can also be represented as the integers 1 and 0 respectively, so essentially we are adding 1 to count whenever it is true.